# Running jooq from testcontainers with a flyway migration via SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, jooq, flyway, testcontainers

I've seen some guides on how to achieve this in java (gradle/maven) but I can't seem to get it to work with an SBT project.

The goal is for my current setup to not require an available postgres database (even if via container) but instead automatically spin one up, initialize it via flyway, run jooq and spin down. I have postgres specific code in my flyway migrations, so using DLLDatabase source instead of a database does not seem like a viable solution (as the migrations fail to be applied to the H2 database).

Any help on how this can be achieved?

Comment: I don't understand if you want to run the migrations for your production database, integration tests or any other context. Could you clarify your context? Also if you already have something that is not working as expected or you are getting an error during the execution share more details about the steps you followed or commands executed. If it is possible, try to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you look at [the jOOQ/testcontainers example from this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/using-testcontainers-to-generate-jooq-code/), it doesn't really rely on Maven all that much. Even within Maven, it uses the maven-groovy-plugin to start/stop testcontainers instances during the build, so I imagine that this should translate to SBT quite directly.

Comment: @GastónSchabas This is to be used on local development and build pipeline, to avoid having to spin up database containers manually to compile the code

Comment: I'm not well familiarized with JOOQ. Based on a quick read I understand that you can use plain sql, generate java/scala code, and some other options. So, it's still a bit confusing the whole context you have or if you are detailing two different use cases. You mention local setup and a build pipeline. If that is the case, please create two different questions. One for the local setup and the other one for the build pipeline adding as much context as you can

Comment: you have [flyway-sbt](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-sbt), a plugin for sbt that lets you write migrations from sbt. Maybe it could be useful for your local setup. You also have [sbt-jooq](https://github.com/kxbmap/sbt-jooq) an sbt plugin for running jooq tasks

Comment: You can also [run flyway migrations from java/scala code](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/quickstart-api-184127575.html) doing something like `Flyway.configure().dataSource(params...).load().migrate();`. That could be helpful for running migrations using testcontainers. You could override the [start hook - afterContainersStart](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-scala/blob/master/docs/src/main/tut/usage.md#startstop-hooks) and run the migrations once the container is started